# javascript how to push static multidimensional

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

In javascript i have the following array

```
// Create array
var imagesAndName =   {
    0 : ["name1", "img/test1.png"],
    1 : ["name2", "img/test2.png"],
    2 : ["name3", "img/test3.png"]
};
```

How can i push new items to this array.

Comment: That's an object, not an array. See [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals) vs [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

Comment: But is it possible to add items to this object

Comment: `imagesAndName[3] = ...`, but I recommend changing it to an array. Then you can just use the `.push` method.

Comment: I have the solution like p.s.w.g said
var test = new Array("name4", "img/test4.png");
imagesAndName[3] = test;

Answer (score 0):

This is an object, so you can add a new attribute as following:

```
imagesAndName[3] = ["name4", "img/test4.png"];
```